# Show and prove if $\sum_{j=1}^\infty{ \frac{(1+(1/j))^{2j}}{e^j}}$ converges or diverges

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

Show and prove if the following series converges or diverges

> $$\sum_{j=1}^\infty{ \frac{(1+(1/j))^{2j}}{e^j}}$$

"I tried the comparison test, the root test, and the ratio test, but got messed up..."

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apply the $\,n$-th root test:

$$\sqrt[n]{\frac{\left(\frac{n+1}n\right)^{2n}}{e^n}}=\frac{\left(\frac{n+1}n\right)^2}{e}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}\frac1e<1\implies\;\text{the series converges}$$

Comment: Helps a lot! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

$(1+1/j)^j
\to e$ as
$j \to \infty$.

Therefore
$(1+1/j)^{2j}
\to e^2$ as
$j \to \infty$,
so each term is about
$e^2/e^j$
which is exponentially small,
so it converges.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: Recall the definition of $e$
$$
e=\lim_{n \to \infty} \bigg(1+\frac{1}{n}\bigg)^n
$$
Notice the numerator can be written as 
$$
\bigg(1+\frac{1}{j}\bigg)^{2j}
$$
and that this is similar to the above definition of $e$. What does this imply about your summation?